# Add Line Break in text file android

Tags: android, android-intent, fileoutputstream

Hi All I am using this code to append text in a txt file.anyone can guide me how i can add line break for this case

```
fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(myFilePath + BlueFreeConstants.logFileName), true);
osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
osw.append("<< " + values + " >>");
osw.flush();
osw.close();
fOut.close();
```

Answer (score 13):

```
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(myFilePath + BlueFreeConstants.logFileName), true);
osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
osw.append("<< " + values + " >>");
osw.append(separator); // this will add new line ;
osw.flush();
osw.close();
fOut.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

`osw.append('\n')`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

```
osw.append("<<"+values+">>\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code to create a multiline text file:

```
FileOutputStream fos=null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw;
    try {
    fos = openFileOutput("login.txt",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(("Line One").getBytes());
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    osw.append("\r\n");
    osw.append("Line Two");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```